# C# DependencyProperty - Use default property for complex type

Tags: c#, uwp, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom control that mimics an `AppBarButton` (but has custom functionality that made it so we could not derive from an `AppBarButton`).

My issue is with the `Icon` property of an `AppBarButton`. The property itself takes a `IconElement`, but if you are creating an `AppBarButton` and specify an `Icon` inline it will default to the `Symbol` enum and create a `SymbolIcon` for you.

My question is: how would I replicate this? I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IconElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.iconelement) is the parent class for these classes:

- [BitmapIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon)
- [FontIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon)
- [PathIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pathicon)
- [SymbolIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon)

So there is no problem to assign a `SymbolIcon` to `AppBarButton`'s `Icon` property. And in UWP XAML system, there is build-in Type Converter support for `SymbolIcon`. For replicating, you should be able to define a [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242362) which type is `IconElement` and then use it as in `AppBarButton`.

For a simple example, I created a Templated Control named "CustomAppBarButton" with a dependency property named "Icon".

*CustomAppBarButton.cs*:

```
public sealed class CustomAppBarButton : Control
{
    public CustomAppBarButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomAppBarButton);
    }

    public IconElement Icon
    {
        get { return (IconElement)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(IconElement), typeof(CustomAppBarButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

*Generic.xaml:*

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomAppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomAppBarButton">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                      Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can use it like the following.

```
<local:CustomAppBarButton Icon="Like" Foreground="Red" />
```

Comment: This does seem to work, however I'm not getting any Intellisense suggestions as I do when using an `AppBarButton`. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @NolanBlew AFAIK, there is no such support for custom control. We have to type manually.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is XAML type converters. They allow you to create custom parsing methods when the content of the property can have a shorthand notation. For example, when you type a point value `Point="10,25"`, there's a built-in parser extracting the x and y values from your string.

You can create your own. [Tim Heuer has an example here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2017/02/15/implement-type-converter-uwp-winrt-windows-10-xaml.aspx).